# Creating JSON with JS in plain text instead of HTML

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am having this piece of code that takes the user location every 5 seconds.

```
<div id="geo" onLoad=""></div>

<script>

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        //Refresh the data
        setTimeout(getLocation, 5000);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {

    var obj = { lat: position.coords.latitude, long: position.coords.longitude };
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
    document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = myJSON;
}
getLocation()
</script>
```

And it prints correctly in the HTML file it is placed in.
The problem is that when I try to reach and parse it comes up with the HTML and I cannot get the result I need.

I have tried adding different headers to the file but with no luck. The one thing I can think of is somehow throwing the results in a PHP file and then just echoing the results there as plain text.

Do you think that this is possible or there is a better idea for achieving JSON in plain text and not HTML?

**UPDATE**
This is what I am getting when I am calling the HTML file
[image]

And this is how I want it to be (if i echo it with PHP)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "reach and parse"? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: please clarify what you want?

Comment: instead of innerHTML you can use textContent

Comment: @ajitkumar, di you mean like this document.getElementById("demo").textContent = myJSON;

Comment: yes, there are multiple options to append text inside a tag like innerText and textContent. You can try both but there slight difference between innerText and textContent. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: Just added some more information and screenshots

Comment: If you're just using PHP to "echo" the contents of a site (e.g. with file_get_contents), that will not execute your Javascript. It will just output your HTML and code. It would be the same as doing "view source" in your browser.

Comment: Well, exactly that's what is happening and I am trying to avoid it. I would easily use PHP only if I could and then I wouldn't have a problem, but as serverside, the PHP cannot get the device location, at least I don't know how. That's why I am using the  JS, but here comes the parsing issue.

Comment: The problem I'm seeing is that the Geolocation api must run on the client, and you are trying to return the JSON directly from the server. In the code above the JS version is simply an HTML being returned for the client to interpret, so it's not being run on the server.

So, could you provide more context as to why you would need the server to tell the client it's location?

Comment: To be honest, your question is not really clear, can you clarify what do you mean by "when I want to reach "? and how you do that ? if you mean by reaching it by a request so tell us how you want to do that , because I have many solutions for this .. but if you want to get the result every 5 seconds , then you can just retreive your object as it is without any other treatement.

Comment: Here is my answer to another comment: Long story short, there is a software that parsing the called file and get the keys and the key values. The software is calling the file just like: domain/geo.html. I don't need to return the result in a loop as I can execute the request to domain/geo.html in a loop on the software end

Answer (score -3):

I don't think you need JSON. You output the position coordinates directly:

`document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = 'lat: ' + position.coords.latitude + ', long: ' + position.coords.longitude;`

Comment: What do you mean when you say you are "calling the HTML file?"

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Long story short, there is a software that parsing the called file and get the keys and the key values. The software is calling the file just like: https://domain/geo.html